# Editing auto-generated .g.cs file possible?

Tags: c#, file, edit, auto-generate

since I have found [BleLab as open source project in UWP C#](https://github.com/IanSavchenko/BleLab), I still edit it but now I have the problem that I have to edit file ([DeviceView](https://pastebin.com/5sQVktnw)).g.cs which ha been auto-generated, according to the following text block.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Unfortunately, I have to do some changes in this file but it gets generated everytime. Do you have any idea what to do?

Best regards

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why do you need to edit it?

Comment: For my purpose it is necessary to change the actually output in functions Update_Name(...) and Update_Uuid(...)

Comment: Ok, I found out that I have to change (DeviceView).cs and (DeviceView).g.cs will be changed